# direct deposit banks - how to have zero monthly fee

Tags: united-states

Some of the banks make the monthly fee zero, as long as you have monthly direct deposits. Is there a way someone can generate that?

Comment: The typical case is to have one's paycheck deposited.

Comment: Related: [As a regular person, can I perform/simulate a direct deposit?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/44434/10997)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Most employers in the US now offer direct deposit (some actually require it). That usually will satisfy the requirement to waive the monthly deposit fees. [Some other ways](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/banking/how-to-avoid-monthly-bank-fees/) are to maintain a daily minimum balance, have a certain number of transactions on the debit card linked to your checking account, etc.